# Em Python, como pegar o diretório temporário padrão?

Tags: python, diretório

Estou fazendo um programa que usa um arquivo temporário para guardar um objeto serializado (pickled). No momento, o programa está gerando no `/tmp`, mas esse caminho é específico do Unix/Linux; queria pegar o caminho do diretório temporário padrão do sistema operacional que o programa for rodar.

Em Java, eu sei que dá pra fazer com `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`.
Qual é a maneira equivalente de fazer isso em Python?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[tempfile.gettempdir()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir) te retorna o diretório utilizado como diretório temporário.

```phyton
import tempfile

print tempfile.gettempdir()
```

Comment: boa, era isso aí. =)

Answer (score 6):

A resposta do talles está tecnicamente correta, mas o ideal é usar `tempfile.TemporaryFile` ou `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` para criar o arquivo temporário ao invés de concatenar o `tempfile.gettempdir()` com um nome constante, assim você garante a unicidade do nome do arquivo evitando que outro arquivo com o mesmo nome seja criado por outra *thread*, processo ou usuário.

```phyton
import tempfile

tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) # pra não ser excluído qdo fizer close()
tmp.write("conteúdo do arquivo")
tmp.close()
```

Comment: Hmm, mas essa solução assume que o arquivo temporário tem vida menor que a execução da aplicação. Nesse caso, essa seria realmente a melhor forma. Mas no meu caso preciso de um arquivo temporário com nome previsível, pois a aplicação vai reutilizar se reiniciar -- todavia ele não precisa sobreviver restart do SO. Por isso queria explicitamente o diretório temporário.